Fix a function for graph calculations
I have a graph:

Here is a data:
$nodes = [
        'f' => ['d g'],
        'b' => ['a d'],
        'g' => ['i'],
        'd' => ['c e'],
        'i' => ['h']
    ];

The function below trying to find a nodes between 2 provided nodes:
function findPathBetweenNodes($start, $end, $nodes) {
        
        foreach ($nodes as $node => $edges) {
            $nodes[$node] = explode(' ', $edges[0]);
        }

        function searchPath($current, $end, $nodes, &$visited) {
            if ($current === $end) {
                return [$current];
            }
            
            $visited[$current] = true;
            foreach ($nodes as $node => $children) {
                if (in_array($current, $children) && !isset($visited[$node])) {
                    $path = searchPath($node, $end, $nodes, $visited);
                    if ($path) {
                        return array_merge([$current], $path);
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        $visited = [];
        $path = searchPath($start, $end, $nodes, $visited);

        if ($path) {
            array_shift($path); 
            array_pop($path);   
        }

        return $path ?: []; 
    }

Test case: print_r(findPathBetweenNodes('h', 'f', $nodes));
Returns correct result:
Array
(
    [0] => i
    [1] => g
)

Test case: print_r(findPathBetweenNodes('f', 'h', $nodes));
Return empty array.
Test case: print_r(findPathBetweenNodes('a', 'c', $nodes));
Returns empty array.
How to fix a function to make it work in other cases too?
Thanks.

For the sake of the sanity of people reading your code please do not define named functions inside of other functions.

Is this graph directed or undirected? Your diagram uses arrows, but your "correct" example traverses a reverse path between the 'start' and 'end' nodes.

@Sammith - Graph direction doesn't matter.

You didn't use the word "correct" to describe the second two test cases; so are we to assume that these result are incorrect?  Do you want a to c to return ['b', 'd']?  I find your explanation and requirements to be Unclear.  What does How to fix a function to make it work in other cases too? mean?  Please provide more test cases and your desired result for each (show sufficiently challenging cases to eliminate ambiguity).

I think there is reason for concern in your desired output because when two input nodes are directly connected, the desired result is an empty array (no additional connections are needed in the path) AND when two input nodes do not have a connection, the desired result is an empty array.  These ambiguous results don't feel usable in a real application.

Does this answer your question? Finding paths in a Undirected Graph

I have reviewed the recommended dupe target.  It is topically related but has greater data complexity, seeks to count potentially multiple satisfying paths, and is more interested in advice on the algorithm than an actual coded solution.  For these reasons, I will not support closure with that dupe target.

I agree with Simon, your node relationship structure is not ideal for this task. The space-delimited values makes unnecessary extra work and cannot be optimized for searching performance. Instead, I recommend building a 2d lookup array because PHP is very fast at searching for keys (versus values searching).
In my recursive function, I included the feature of avoiding potential circular/infinite recursion by removing/consuming elements from the lookup array with each deeper traversal.
My snippet is not designed or tested to work in a scenario where multiple node paths may occur.  If this is a possibility, please specify this in your question body and provide more challenging sample data (or ask a new question).
To differentiate complete/successful paths from unconnected nodes, I've designed my function to return null to indicate no qualifying path.
Code: (Demo)
function findWayPoints(array $lookup, $start, $end, array $path = []): ?array
{
    if (isset($lookup[$start][$end])) {
        return $path;  // full path found; no need to further recurse
    }
    foreach ($lookup[$start] ?? [] as $conn => $irrelevant) {
        $result = findWayPoints(
            array_diff_key($lookup, [$start => null]),  // eliminate circular/infinite recursion
            $conn,  // change starting node in next call
            $end,
            array_merge($path, [$conn])  // append current match to path
        );
        if ($result !== null) {
            return $result;
        }
    }
    return null;  // dead end; kill path
}

function buildLookup($nodes) {
    $lookup = [];
    foreach ($nodes as $k => [$connections]) {
        foreach (explode(' ', $connections) as $conn) {
            $lookup[$k][$conn] = true;
            $lookup[$conn][$k] = true;
        }
    }
    return $lookup;    
}

$nodes = [
    'f' => ['d g'],
    'b' => ['a d'],
    'g' => ['i'],
    'd' => ['c e'],
    'i' => ['h']
];
$lookup = buildLookup($nodes);

   
echo json_encode(findWayPoints($lookup, 'h', 'f'));
echo "\n---\n";
echo json_encode(findWayPoints($lookup, 'f', 'h'));
echo "\n---\n";
echo json_encode(findWayPoints($lookup, 'a', 'c'));
echo "\n---\n";
echo json_encode(findWayPoints($lookup, 'a', 'b'));
echo "\n---\n";
echo json_encode(findWayPoints($lookup, 'a', 'h'));
echo "\n---\n";
echo json_encode(findWayPoints($lookup, 'i', 'j'));

Output:
["i","g"]
---
["g","i"]
---
["b","d"]
---
[]
---
["b","d","f","g","i"]
---
null


Thanks for solution. How to modify it to find all possible routes?

Now that this has been answered, it's a good idea to not move the goal posts.  I recommend asking a new question, referencing this page as an insufficiently challenging [mcve], then show your new MCVE and explain where your new challenge is.

The $nodes array isn't configured as an undirected graph. The picture shown suggests it should be
$nodes = [
    'a' => ['b'],
    'b' => ['a d'],
    'c' => ['d'],
    'd' => ['b c e f'],
    'e' => ['d'],
    'f' => ['d g'],
    'g' => ['f i'],
    'h' => ['i'],
    'i' => ['g h']
];

For print_r(findPathBetweenNodes('f', 'h', $nodes));
Array
(
    [0] => g
    [1] => i
)

For print_r(findPathBetweenNodes('a', 'c', $nodes));
Array
(
    [0] => b
    [1] => d
)


Will you be writing any code to remedy the input structure?

@mickmackusa I don't like the code, but it appears to work, so far as I tested anyway. Feel free to rewrite it.

Thanks Simon but I prefer not to change (extend) the $nodes variable.
